# JFRAME, MouseListener Draw a Circle

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener, actionevent

I need your help
I have to draw an ellipse (coloured) in the center of the window.
On the bottom are buttons.

- One button "Exit", for closing the window
- One button "Change Color" , color changing

When I click the mouse (anywhere) there have to appear dods.

- Last but not least -> When the toggle button "Show edges" is pressed, connections between the circles appear (lines)

Please help me..
this is a homework and I REALLY don't know how to do it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you.  Create a model using plain Java classes, create a view using Swing components, and create one or more controllers using ActionListeners.  The [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern is usually a good pattern to follow when creating a Swing appication.